# Mysql database design for blocking events on a calendar

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I have a simple calendar on PHP and MySQL, it stores events in a simple format:

```
id int
name varchar    
start datetime 
end datetime
```

What I need to do, and can't find a reliable way to do it, is to "block" certain time slot so that there can't be any other event in that time window.

What I'm trying to find basically is the mysql query to check if the new selected time frame is occupied:

If I go this way:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE new_event_start => start AND  new_event_end =< end;
```

It fails to find an event that starts before `new_event_start` and ends after `new_event_end`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about your design? Does the presence of a table row mean the time is occupied? Or, do you have a row, whose individual field or fields indicate the time is occupied?

Comment: Yes, the presence of a row means that the time frame between the datetimes "start" and "end" on that row is occupied and must be unique... so I'm trying to find the best way to query the table for occupied time before inserting a new row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a logic question, not a language or technology question.

You need to test for several cases:

> ```
> End of new event is between the beginning and end of blocked period
> OR
> Beginning of new event is between the beginning and end of blocked period
> OR
> Beginning of new event is before the beginning of the blocked period and the end is after the end of the blocked period
> ```

That will catch all events that would overlap a blocked period.

Comment: Nice, so...
     SELECT *  
     FROM events  
     WHERE (new_event_start between start and end)  
     OR (new_event_end between start and end)  
     OR (new_event_start <= start AND new_event_end >= end);  
Am I correct?

Comment: For some reason my code won't show up as code even when I indent the four spaces...

Comment: Yes, that's right, given that the blocked period is bounded by 'start' and 'end' and the new event is bounded by 'new_event_start' and 'new_event_end'.

Answer (score 0):

Use OR in WHERE.

SELECT * FROM events WHERE (new_event_start => start AND new_event_end =< end) OR (new_event_start <= start AND new_event_end >= end) OR ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select count(*) from events 
where (start between new_event_start and new_event_end) 
OR (end between new_event_start and new_event_end);
```

Comment: How would that catch an event that starts before the window and ends after the window? Such an event would still overlap the window.